# Sealed keyword in association with override

Tags: c#, overriding, sealed

Is it always necessary to follow the `sealed` keyword with `override` in the signature of a method like the below code:

```
public sealed override string Method1(){.....}
```

I mean, if I want to "seal" the method within the base class without overriding, is the `override` keyword still necessary?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Sealing a method only makes sense if you override it.

What happens here is the following:
You are overriding a method from a base class (`override`) and tell the compiler that classes derived from *your* class are no longer allowed to override this method (`sealed`).

If the method is a new one declared by you in your class and you want to prevent derived classes from overriding it, simply don't declare it as virtual.

If the method is declared in a base class but is not overridable sealing it wouldn't make any sense, because it already can't be overriden.

Comment: I didn't mean that. I want to know if say Myclass does not inherit from any class and has a method which I want to be sealed, this method was not overriden in MyClass, but declared for the very first time.

Comment: @VictorMukherjee: If you are the one declaring the method you already have full control. If you don't want it to be overriden in derived classes, simply don't make it virtual. See also the second to last paragraph in my answer.

Comment: ok, got it. Sorry, forgot about this virtual thing, since I know java, experimenting with c# for just a couple of days.

Comment: @VictorMukherjee: Yes, that's an important difference: In Java, methods are per default virtual and you need to explicitly declare them as non-virtual via the `final` keyword. In C# it is the other way around: Per default, methods are non-virtual and you have to explicitly declare them as virtual via the `virtual` keyword.

Comment: There are also the `abstract` methods that are like virtual methods but **must** be overridden.

Answer (score 5):

I think Mr. Hilgarth has provided the best answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13858411/1977152) 
, but just to add something new for programmers who have a previous background in **Java**(like myself), I think most programmers new to C#, tend to confuse `sealed` with `final` in `Java` with respect to overriding.

In **Java**, the default behaviour without specifying `"any"` modifier is that the method ***can*** be *overriden* in its derived classes.

While in **C#**, the default behaviour is that the method ***cannot*** be *overriden* unless explicitly specified using the `virtual` keyword.

Hope this helps to supplement the best answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it technically is possible .... however, the solution is in my option kinda dirty.

Imagine having a class `A` (either in your code base or an external library):

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void M () { /* implementation */ }
}
```

You could define an (abstract) class `B : A` as follows:

```
public class B : A
{
    public sealed override void M() => base.M();
}
```

Any class `C : B`  would not be able to override `A.M` as you have sealed the method (even though you made no semantic changes).