# C# Sealed Prevent a method to be derived

Tags: c#, inheritance, sealed

I'm trying to prevent my Base Class to derived one of its method, but it seems impossible to do it in the way I like, I assume I'm doing it wrong.

Could you help please ? :)
I really want to use successfully the sealed keyword !

Here is a bit of code :

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public void MyMethod1(string input)
    {
        // Doing stuff here
    }
    public sealed void MyMethod2(string input)
    {
        // Doing stuff here
    }
}
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    // Other fields and stuff over there
}
```

What happened is problematic, the keyword sealed isn't allow on a method which is in a first level of derivation.
I only have one single derivation level, and what I'm looking for is avoiding MyMethod2 to be derived in the DerivedClass.

But it doesn't seem to be ok :/
Any advice or correction ?

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT : After many comments and lunch pause I'll try to explicit my question !

What I'm try to really do is to prevent my class to use one of the method "she" inherits.
Some of you mentioned to use composition instead of inheritance, because it appeared I misunderstood its meaning.

I thought composition was only present in UML not in code.
What a composition sounds like in C# code ?

Comment: I just don't understand why you need that method to be sealed. If you are just making it for the purpose of not to be overridden then leave it normal it can not be overridden until marked as virtual or abstract.

Comment: This is also a bit of a warning sign that the way classes have been designed is probably wrong.

Comment: whats wrong in making the method "private' ??

Comment: @JenishRabadiya it can't be overridden yes, but  the derived class can still access to that method, which I don't want, this is why I'm trying to seled it :/

Comment: @Fikkwix Can't you make it just private to prevent it accessible in derived class?

Comment: @JenishRabadiya If I make it private, I'll not be able to access it from exterior, same as protected, or I need to access it from another program which use this class as a compiled DLL. But I don't want the derived class to be able to access it !
I should had precise it :/

Comment: @Fikkwix If it's accessible to the outside then it is accessible to derived classes as well.  Overriding and sealing are different than accessibility of a method.

Comment: @Fikkwix also note injecting such a behavior defeats the use of inheritance.

Comment: This seems like a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  You might need composition instead of inheritance, but we can not tell from the general example given.

Comment: unlike java, in c# methods are sealed by default. you add the "virtual" keyword before a method to make it overridable in the subclass. You may want to look into a similar question I asked long ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858384/sealed-keyword-in-association-with-override

Comment: @juharr  what advice could you give me ?

Comment: @Fikkwix When posting a question it is good to give a general example of the problem, but it is also good to give a broader explanation of what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is the first level, it is not overridable by derived class unless marked `virtual` or `abstract`.

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void MyMethod1(string input)
    {
        // Doing stuff here
    }
    public void MyMethod2(string input)
    {
        // Doing stuff here
    }
}
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public override void MyMethod1(string input){..}

    /// MyMethod2 is not overridable
}
```

---

Based on your comments below, it seems like what you really want is composition, not inheritance; that is to say that `DerivedClass` should be able to access some functionality on the `BaseClass` but should not be able to change it in any way. This may look like the below for your class example.

```
public class CompositeFunctionality
{
    public void MyMethod1(string input)
    {
        // Doing stuff here
    }
}
public class BaseClass
{
    private CompositeFunctionality composite = new CompositeFunctionality();
    public void MyMethod2(string input)
    {
        // this is accessible in the base class
        composite.MyMethod1();
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public void MyMethod3(string input)
    {
         // do whatever you want
         // but composite is not accessible here
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want the method to be override at all, I just want to be not accessible from the derived class.

Comment: @Fikkwix then you're funamentally misunderstanding inheritance. It sounds more like you want composition than inheritance.

Comment: @Fikkwix see update - its a bit of a contrived example, but hopefully you get the gist

Comment: I use your method it works, but not in the way I'd like to...
In fact with your method, in the DerivedClass MyMethod2 will be still accessible...
I should change the way I think I guess >_<'

Comment: I was already using a composition inside my code.
But not in a correct way, that's explain everything which was going wrong ^^
Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 4):

You can only seal a method/property that overrides a virtual method in a base class. Your `MyMethod2` isn't virtual, so can't be sealed. In fact it's implicitly sealed by the fact it isn't virtual!

Answer (score 1):

You need another level of inheritance to be able to use `sealed`. You can mark the method `virtual` in the base class, and `override sealed` it in the second class.

You could make the "absolute base" abstract, so it's not possible to instantiate it, then inherit from it to implement and seal it:

```
public abstract class VeryBaseClass
{
    public abstract void MyMethod2(string input);
}

public class BaseClass : VeryBaseClass
{
    public override sealed void MyMethod2(string input)
    {

    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    // Other fields and stuff over there
}
```

But like [@Jenish says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29208598/c-sharp-sealed-prevent-a-method-to-be-derived/29208645#comment46627312_29208598), methods are sealed by default in C#.

On the contrary, to be able to override a method it must be marked `virtual` anyway, so your problem doesn't seem to be a problem at all. Just mark `MyMethod1` as `virtual` so you *can* override it, and `MyMethod2` will remain non-virtual so non-overridable at all.

Comment: Does your solution act like a composition link to a inheritance ?
Plus it will work, just I'd like to avoid to add another class to my project if it's not absolutely necessary.

Comment: I tried it like you wrote it, but still my method MyMethod2 is available from my DerivedClass, I don't understand why...

Comment: @Fikkwix that means you don't know what `sealed` means. If you want to hide a method from outside that class, mark it `private` or `protected`.

Comment: Maybe, could you explain ?
To me sealed means the method will not be present in the derived class, however it seems I misunderstood...

Answer (score 0):

The sealed keyword is implied to any method in a base class that isn't already virtual or abstract (and therefore overridable).

See this [link on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1138c2b3-7ec8-49ef-b50d-fd5b860a3995/sealed-methods-in-base-class?forum=csharplanguage) for more information

Answer (score 0):

try like this..

```
class Base 
{
 public virtual void Test() { ... }
}

class Subclass1 : Base 
{
 public sealed override void Test() { ... }
}

class Subclass2 : Subclass1 
{
 public override void Test() { ... } // FAILS!
// If `Subclass1.Test` was not sealed, it would've compiled correctly.
}
```

Comment: I've seen that example out there, but it's not what I'm trying to do.
I don't want the method to be accessible at all in the derived class.

Answer (score 0):

I am renaming methods for a better understanding.

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public void MethodToBeInherited(string input)
    {
        // Doing stuff here
    }
    public void MethodNotToBeInherited(string input)
    {
        // Doing stuff here
    }
}
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    // Other fields and stuff over there
    //MethodoBeInherited should be available
    //MethodNotToBeInherited should not be available
}
```

The condition you want is not possible using this kind of hierarchy(**Is a relationship**), because DervicedClass is a BaseClass. So on the rules of inheritance you are bound to have access to all BaseClass public methods.

But there is an alternative to solve this using - **Has a relationship**. 
Its not possible to inherit and achieve what you wanted as you will break the inheritance rule. So making the derived class composed of a base class you would be able to achieve it.

```
interface I
{
    void MethodToBeInherited(string input)
}

class BaseClass
{
    public void MethodToBeInherited(string input)
    {
        // Doing stuff here
    }
    public void MethodNotToBeInherited(string input)
    {
        // Doing stuff here
    }
}

class DerivedClass : I
{
    public void MethodToBeInherited(string input)
    {
        b.MethodToBeInherited(input);
    }

    private BaseClass b;
}
```

Comment: An interface isn't what I expected but why not !
I'll try this if there are no other solutions working. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: This doesn't seem right.  The interface has a method called `MethodToBeInherited` but the `DrivedClass` that implements that interface has a method called `MethodNotToBeInherited`?  Did you mean to apply the interface to the `BaseClass` so that the `MethodNotToBeInherited` is not visible to the `DerivedClass` and then refer to the interface in the `DerivedClass`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it, it was a typo. I wanted to expose `MethodToBeInherited` and hide the other one. Corrected the post.

Comment: @CarbineCoder I guess that's one interruptation.  I thought the OP didn't want the method visible from within the `Derived` class, which it is in your answer.  But, maybe they didn't want it visible from outside the `Derived` class.  But then the interface should probably be implemented by both classes in that case.

Comment: True thats another way, its just upto the OP to decide. But if Interface is implemented by both Base and derived, they are no longer base and derived and they will lie on the same level of hierarchy. And if it goes like `Derived:Base,I` then the method will end up being visible. Then again its up to the OP to choose the approach based on the context of his problem.